# How can I use Firefox webdriver in pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, selenium, pythonanywhere

I can use Chromedriver easyly in [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) but how can I use Firefox driver in pythonanywhere's python script ?

this is how I use chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
print("Done")
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try ? options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--headless")

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here: unfortunately Firefox doesn't work well enough to be fully supported on PythonAnywhere now -- it's too resource-intensive.  Chrome is more lightweight, so it's the only Selenium option we support.

(Interestingly, it used to be the other way around -- Firefox was more lightweight, and was the one that we supported.  But the browsers have changed over time, so we have to change with them.)